# 'Can\'t connect to MySQL server on \'db\' Django-Restframework with Mysql in docker

Tags: python, mysql, django, docker, django-rest-framework

I have dockerized my existing Django Rest project which uses MySQL database.

**Dockefile**

```
FROM python:3.6

ENV PYTHONUNBUFFERED 1
RUN mkdir /code
WORKDIR /code
COPY . /code/
RUN pip install -r requirements.txt
```

**requirements.txt**

django
djongo
django-rest-framework
wheel
pillow
mysqlclient
django-cors-headers

**docker-compose.yml**

```
version: '3'
volumes:
    portainer:

services:
  db:
    image: mysql
    environment:
      MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD: docker
      MYSQL_DATABASE: docker
      MYSQL_USER: docker
      MYSQL_PASSWORD: docker
    ports:
      - "3306:3306"

  web:
    build: .
    command: bash -c "python manage.py makemigrations && python manage.py migrate && python manage.py runserver 0.0.0.0:8000 "
    volumes: 
      - .:/code
    ports:
      - "8000:8000"
    links:
     - db
  portainer:
   image: portainer/portainer
   ports:
   - "9000:9000"
   volumes:
    - /var/run/docker.sock:/var/run/docker.sock
    - portainer:/data
```

**setting.py**

```
        'ENGINE': 'django.db.backends.mysql', #django.db.backends.mysql 
        'NAME': 'docker', #local: libraries #server: 
        'USER': 'docker', #root #root
        'PASSWORD': 'docker', #local: root #server: 
        'HOST': 'db', #local: localhost  #server:
        'PORT': '3306',
```

My command 'docker-compose up -d --build' are successful but the restapp container was not started so while checking logs it was showing this error `django.db.utils.OperationalError: (2003, 'Can\'t connect to MySQL server on \'db\' (111 "Connection refused")')`.

Comment: The very same code worked for me. But I faced another issue, which is `django.db.utils.OperationalError: (2059, "Authentication plugin 'caching_sha2_password' cannot be loaded` which is not relevant for this question

Answer (score 1):

This may happen if your application container (`web` here) starts before your database is fully initialized.

You must wait until `db` service is started (more precisely, until `mysql` is accepting connections) before starting your application (`python manage.py makemigrations && python manage.py migrate && python manage.py runserver 0.0.0.0:8000`).

For that, you can use `wait-for-it.sh` script (check https://docs.docker.com/compose/startup-order/) before running your python commands. Alternatively, you could use a restart policy on your `web` service (https://docs.docker.com/compose/compose-file/#restart_policy) to automatically restart your service (until database is up).